# @angular/forms and ng-packagr

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-module, ng-packagr

I have an angular module that imports the @angular/forms module. I publish with ng-packagr and when I import this angular module I get an error.

Usually this error would be caused by not importing the formsModule. However, it's imported.

Has anyone experienced this issue before or know what is causing it?

```
rejection: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FormControl$1 -> NgForm]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FormControl$1 -> NgForm]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm!
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem. As I've already stated, the formsModule is already imported to the module.